# Showing data types in Curry

Tags: show, typeclass, pretty-print, read-eval-print-loop, curry

Does [Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29) have the ability to show or pretty print data types inside the REPL (using [PAKCS](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/) or [MCC](http://danae.uni-muenster.de/~lux/curry/))? In Haskell, this functionality is impemented using [the type class `Show`](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/blob/master/GHC/Show.lhs#L60). However, no maintained Curry implementation implements type classes. Glancing at the PAKCS libraries, it appears that no abstract data type is given a canonical representation for the user to interact with, but several have separate functions defined for pretty printing them.

For reference, I am implementing several abstract data types for a personal project. Because I have no intention of packaging the code into a compiled program with an interactive user interface, something approximating Haskell's `show` function would be convenient.

Comment: For information for those interested in the implementation of such a thing in Haskell: fryguybob has studied how `Show` is being used in GHCi (a Haskell REPL); he gave a short summary here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535512/how-to-hack-ghci-or-hugs-so-that-it-prints-unicode-chars-unescaped/5621230#5621230 .