# Does the hiredis Redis library create its own thread for async callbacks

Tags: c++, c, database, redis

I am using Redis in a multithreaded environment, and have a question as to how it operates. I am using the hiredis c library in my c++ application.

My question is this: If I am using the asynchronous mode when a callback is fired will the callback be handled in another thread created by the Redis client? As in will the thread where the call was created not be affected by the handling of the callback? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Redis client does not create any additional clent threads, and works in existing thread.

The Redis worked in another (main) process. The redis API which you use worked in your local process and use interprocess communication to main process. Async request mean that your process or thread put task to another, and after that may do any other yout task or wait event. Some time later async reply arrived to your application and available for use. You application must use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop or any async management system that notify you by calling callback to handle event (in this case redis answer).

Asyncronous architecture mean that you runing event loop that call callback handlers for each event. When callback called you can create number of asynchronous tasks. Once task created, it supposed than when task done or error occur the callback event handler will be called. Callback may be assigned to start app or to new web connection appear. When callback called you can create the redis task, and later result event callback will be called. All things in current thread. I нou have multiple thread, reasonable to expect that you have one event loop per each thread.

Single threaded nature of Redis: http://redis.io/topics/latency#single-threaded-nature-of-redis

The client socket is put in non-blocking state since Redis uses multiplexing and non-blocking I/O. http://redis.io/topics/clients This mean that your client will never be blocked.

From Redis 2.4 threads in Redis used only in order to perform some slow I/O operations in the background, mainly related to disk I/O, but this does not change the fact that Redis serves all the requests using a single thread.

Comment: I understand how libuv style event libraries work. That is not my question. My question is in relation to inner working dynamics of the redis client library, and where callbacks are handled. There HAS to be another thread involved because otherwise it would be blocking, unless that is the DB operations only happened when the thread blocks for some reason. In which case a while(true){} would cause the async operations to never happen. My question is which thread handles the callback.

Comment: Server (main) threan serve the task and send reply to your thread. Your thread is not blocked becouse nonblocked socked used for transport. When socket transport done, you may do with data what you need in your thread. Which reason you mean for block your thread?

Comment: Even if a non blocking socket is used the socket status has to be checked by a thread. If the main thread is doing a calculation then it cannot handle the the socket even if the socket is non blocking. In addition the library does not require you to call a function to give it control of dispatch for a thread like libuv (an event library). There has to be another thread involved in this somewhere.

Comment: Do not warry about it. This is operation system task. This is different and implementation dependendtly . For more information refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue

Comment: I have written an epoll server, and understand how it works. EPoll produces a list of events. This list of events has to be checked to know when data has arrived. Because this checking is not being done by the main thread (no function is being called to initiate it like how libuv does) then another thread HAS to be doing the checking. There is no other way. EPoll still requires a thread to be constantly checking it. It just means that the OS generates events instead of 1000 threads each checking one socket.

Comment: When you have a task for calculate do it. When calculate is done return from callback to event loop that call epoll checking. Are your redis socked added in same epoll list? If you can not integrate all sockets to single epoll than you are need another process or thread to work with it. But need to figure out reason why you can not use single thread with one epoll. For example hiredis works easily with any event library: https://github.com/redis/hiredis#asynchronous-api

Comment: Check please wether available to change database tag to asynchronous tag of question?

Comment: @erick2red, you say strange things. Read first string of answer again and first string of hiredis readme. The hiredis is minimalistic client of redis server. Hiredis is just redis api through ipc and *works with any event library*. You can search through hiredis sources for any create thread functions if doubt. Do all things related to redisAsyncContext in one thread if you use multithreading. A redisAsyncContext is not thread-safe. Make multiple connections one per thread if you very want to use reids in different threads

Comment: @oklas. I apologize, you're right. I miss read the answer yesterday. What I think it needs now is a bit of style.

Answer (score 2):

Hiredis calls the callback when you call redisAsyncHandlerRead(). Therefore the callbacks are called on whatever thread you used to call redisAsyncHandlerRead().

I believe a minimal Redis async example, in Linux-ish C, would look like this (error checking removed for clarity):

```
#include "async.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myRedisCallback(redisAsyncContext *c, void *typeless_reply, void *priv_data) {
    redisReply *r = (redisReply *)typeless_reply;
    if (r->type == REDIS_REPLY_STRING)
        printf("foo is %s\n", r->str);
}

int main() {
    redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("localhost", 6379);
    redisAsyncCommand(c, myRedisCallback, NULL, "GET foo");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        redisAsyncHandleWrite(c); // This sends the command.
        redisAsyncHandleRead(c); // This calls the callback if the reply has been received.
        usleep(10000); // A real app would do something here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```