# Outputting Haskell GHCi command results to a txt file

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.

I am having a really difficult time outputting command results from GHCi to a file. I was wondering if someone can give me a simple explanation on how to do this? The examples I have found online so far seem over complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a function `mungeData` and you do

```
 ghci> mungeData [1..5]
 [5,2,5,2,4,6,7,4,6,78,4,7,5,3,57,7,4,67,4,6,7,4,67,4]
```

### writeFile

You can write this to file like this:

```
ghci> writeFile "myoutput.txt" (show (mungeData [1..5])
```

I'd be inclined to write

```
ghci> writeFile "myoutput.txt" $ show $ mungeData [1..5]
```

to get rid of a few brackets.

### Reading it back in

You could get that back using

```
ghci> fmap (read::String -> [Int]) $ readFile "myoutput.txt"
```

### One number per line

You could output it a line per number like this:

```
ghci> writeFile "myoutput'.txt" $ unlines.map show $ mungeData [1..5]
```

which reads back in as

```
ghci> fmap (map read.lines::String -> [Int]) $ readFile "myoutput'.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not work for me. I am getting a parse error. I have a function that adds one to every element of the list. I wrote something like: `writeFile "myoutput.txt" (show(addOne(x)` where x is a list such as 1:2:3:4:5:[]

Comment: You don't need brackets round `x`, and you missed a close bracket. Use: `writeFile "myoutput.txt" (show (addOne x))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @AndrewC, what if I am running tests by loading a Tests.hs file, and then typing main in the prompt and hitting enter to execute say 100 test cases. What if I wanted that to be written to a file? Using your method to print out main did not work for me. I appreciate any assistance with this ;)

Comment: You can either rewrite `main` to write to file instead of to screen or if that's too complicated you can compile it with `ghc Test.hs -O2 -o test.exe` (just `test` on linux/MacOS/unix etc) then redirect its output: `test.exe > testoutput.txt`

Answer (score 7):

[This post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/) describes how to colorize your GHCi output (GHC >= 7.6). Instead of a prettyprinter, you could specify a logging function. For example, add the following to your `.ghci.conf`:

```
:{
let logFile = "/home/david/.ghc/ghci.log"
    maxLogLength = 1024 -- max length of a single write
    logPrint x = appendFile logFile (take maxLogLength (show x) ++ "\n") >> print x
:}
:set -interactive-print=logPrint
```

This will log GHCi's output to `ghci.log`.

- The logging file must already exist, otherwise `appendFile` will complain. You'll have to create that manually.
- It has to fit in a `let` statement, otherwise GHCi will reject it. Use `:{ :}` to add multiline support in GHCi.
- Apparently, using `:l` gets rid of all imports you've made in your `ghci.conf`, therefore you're limited to Prelude functions. The Reddit post mentions that you can somehow redefine `:l`, but I don't know anythng about that. (If you know how to do this, you can of course automatically generate the logfile if it doesn't exist.)

Comment: Great! That's a use of the feature which [resulted from a StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13113906/94687) thanks to bravit (Vitaly Bragilevsky).