# Redirecting Haskell GHCi output to text file

Tags: haskell, file-io, cmd, executable, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outputting Haskell GHCi command results to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595934/outputting-haskell-ghci-command-results-to-a-txt-file)

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to redirect test cases output results to a text file. The way it is set up now, is a `AddAllTestCases.hs` contains all the test cases I need to run in order to test a function I created. I run the test cases on GHCi by loading `AddAllTestCases.hs` and then simply typing `main` and hitting enter. That causes test case output results to print inside the GHCi perfectly.

Because there hundreds of test cases, I need to redirect output results to text file.

Attempt #1:

```
writeFile "myoutput.txt" $ show $ main
```

I get the following error:

`No instance for (Show(IO())) arising from a use of show`

Attempt #2 in CMD (trying to create an executable, then outputting executable results to text file):

`ghc --make AddAllTests.hs -o testResults.exe`

Which gives me the following error:

`Warning: output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated because there is no Min module`

This is weird because when I am using GHCi (attempt #1) and I type in `main` it executes everything perfectly, which I would assume, implies that there is a main module?

I greatly appreciate any help with redirecting test case results to a text file.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `Main` module (and a `main` action) to produce an executable. You can rename your module to `Main`, or you can specify the module to be considered `Main` on the command line,

```
ghc --make -main-is AddAllTests AddAllTests.hs -o testResults.exe
```

to produce an executable without a module named `Main`.

A method without compiling would be

```
ghc AddAllTests.hs -e "main" > testResults.txt
```

Another method would be to have a file in which you just list all test cases,

```
3 + 2 :: Rational
reverse "foobar"
:q
```

and run `ghci` with redirected in- and output

```
ghci < testCases > testResults.txt
```

Comment: +1 Fantastic and clear response, worked perfectly, thank you!