# How to log all output in GHCI Prompt

Tags: haskell

I would like to log all **output and input** to a file in GHCI.

What I have done so far:

I have tried to use `:h` in GHCI, but I did not see any `options` or `flags` to do so.

I also have tried to search some configuration for `.ghc/ghci.conf` and I still have no luck.

I knew the `.ghc/ghci_history` stores all the input :commands.

My GHCI version:  version 7.10.3

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688119/redirecting-haskell-ghci-output-to-text-file#14688202

Comment: Thx, I saw the post before. But I'm looking for something that put in the ./ghc/ghci.conf and log all my output and input in the GHCI prompt.

Comment: `screen -L ghci` but this will log *literally* all input and output, including your editing actions.

Comment: I use tmux currently, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The historic unix command for that is [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).